# Table Cell not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, tablecell

I've designed a custom table cell as follows:
[image]

However, it is rendering as follows:

[image]

as you see, the second label is going in the next cell. Any idea how can I solve this issue and make the cell appear as I designed it?

Comment: Have you tried this? [label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

Comment: And make sure about the frame of the label is properly handled.

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 subtitle in the defaultcell or display the subtitle in 2 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `UITableViewDelegate`
 `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

This method:

> Asks the delegate for the height to use for a row in a specified
>   location.

Give a minimum height for each row here. Also if different row have different height according to the content, you have to calculate the height according to the content in that case. Something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *stringText=[array objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [stringText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName: "yourFont" size: fontSize] constrainedToSize:maxCGSize];
    return labelSize.height + padding;
}
```